# Async vs manual Threadcreation HttpListener

Tags: c#, multithreading

I Implemented the HttpListener to process requests.

And now I am not sure wether it is better to use Async implementation over mine.

Mine does something similiar to this:

```
while (this.httpListener.IsListening)
{
    processRequest(this.httpListener.GetContext());
}

void processRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
{
    ...
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(....
    ...
}
```

So in short, I process all requests in a single thread at first, and then split them up, using ThreadPool.

Is there any drawback compared to Async-Implementation or is it even bad?

Comment: It seems fine if  you don't do something time consuming in the first `...`.

Comment: All that is done is create some HandleContainer for TimeOut related stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important thing to realise is that using `async` does NOT create a new thread. Of course, the function you're calling might do so, but `async` alone doesn't.

For IO, many Microsoft implementations of Async methods use IO Completion Ports at some point. This means they get called back from a single dedicated thread managed by the OS rather having to create a new thread just to wait for some IO.

This is a much better approach, particularly for servers that might have a lot of incoming requests. Each thread has a huge overhead.

Therefore, I recommend you use the `async` implementation where possible.

Comment: Well the approach is meant for small scale services, I dont know what you define alot, but I guess lets say 16 isnt.

Comment: Would it be bad to implement the Async way, and use the processRequest ?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean... It would be fine to have the processRequest() using the Async approach though.